# Need the status column as output if a person is Booked or Not Booked on the basis of input of Date Range in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I have a table `xxtab` having data as

```
 NAME  | DATE_FROM  | DATE_TO
---------------------------------
 Rahul | 12/14/2015 | 12/18/2015 
 Rahul | 12/20/2015 | 12/21/2015 
 Divya | 12/29/2015 | 12/30/2015 
 Rahul | 12/22/2015 | 12/24/2015
```

Now I need a column `Status` having output as `'Booked'` or `'Not Booked'` on the basis of Input Date range. Now if for a particular person, input `DATE_FROM` and date_to falls on the date range in the table,then it should show output of status as 'Booked'

Suppose I give Input as

```
Date_from = '15-Dec-2015'
Date_to   = '19-Dec-2015'
```

Then I expect this result:

```
 NAME  | STATUS
--------------------
 Rahul | Booked
 Divya | Not Booked
```

i.e for one unique name, I need only one record.

I tried to use this query:

```
select name,
       CASE                    
       WHEN (to_char('15-Dec-2015') between Date_from and Date_to                        
             OR to_char('19-Dec-2015') between Date_from and Date_to)                                        
       THEN 'Booked'                    
       ELSE 'Not Booked'                    
       END Status 
 from xxtab;
```

But I am getting multiple records for the same person.

```
 NAME  | STATUS
--------------------
Rahul  | Booked
Rahul  | Not Booked
Divya  | Not Booked
Rahul  | Not Booked
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a MIN as 'Booked' < 'Not Booked':

```
select name,
   MIN(CASE                    
         WHEN DATE '2015-12-15' <= date_to
          AND DATE '2015-12-19' >= date_from                                        
         THEN 'Booked'                    
         ELSE 'Not Booked'                    
       END) Status 
from   xxtab
group by name
```

I changed your overlapping logic (which reports all as "Not Booked" when your requested range is from 13.12. to 31.12.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 select distinct(name), CASE                    
             WHEN (to_char('15-Dec-2015') between Date_from and Date_to                        
              OR to_char('19-Dec-2015') between Date_from and Date_to)                                        
              THEN 'Booked'                    
             ELSE 'Not Booked'                    
              END Status  from   demo1 ;
```

You can try this. It will retrieve unique records if the Output of Status for a particular name is unique